# the highcharts can't use addPoint() after new Highcharts.Chart(options)

Tags: highcharts, redraw

any helper.

I've a problem that when i use addPoint method for charts.series and it doesn't work.

I got some data from database and assign it to the options.series.data for the first time, it works.

like this: options.series.data = data_from_database

```
       charts = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

but when i used the addPoint method on charts.series, it failed and the chart doesn't redraw.

like this: var arr_time_status = [get_time(), cpu_status];

```
       charts.series[i].addPoint(arr_time_status, true, true);
```

i just want to use the addPoint method to drive the chart to redraw.

can anybody help? thank you so much.

```
`var charts;
$(function () {
    var options = {
        chart:{
            renderTo: 'new'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'CPU for PM2'
            //x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'MIX-CPU'
            //x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            maxZoom: 1000 * 60 * 10,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                minute: '%H:%M',
                hour:   '%H:%M',
                day:    '%H:%M',
                week:   '%H:%M',
                month:  '%H:%M',
                year:   '%H:%M'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'CPU Load Average'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        plotOption: {
            series: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'swing'
                },
                marker :{
                    radius: 1
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', this.x) +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: '1/Mins',
            color: '#2EFF74',
            data:[]
        }, {
            name: '5/Mins',
            color: '#C361ED',
            data: []
        },{
            name: '15/Mins',
            color: '#BF0B23',
            data: []
        }]
    };

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: true
        }
    });

    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/history', function(results){
        var a = [];
        var b = [];
        var c = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
            a[i] = [Number(results[i].milliSeconds), results[i].oneMin];
            b[i] = [Number(results[i].milliSeconds), results[i].fiveMins];
            c[i] = [Number(results[i].milliSeconds), results[i].fifteenMins];
        };
        options.series[0].data = a;
        options.series[1].data = b;
        options.series[2].data = c;
        charts = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
    setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/keys?name=MIX', function(dataUrl){
            $.getJSON(dataUrl[0].v,function(dataBody){
                var time = new Date();
                for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    function get_time() {
                        var t = Date.UTC(
                            time.getFullYear(),
                            time.getMonth(),
                            time.getDate(),
                            time.getHours(),
                            time.getMinutes(),
                            time.getSeconds());
                        return t;
                    };

                    //Creating an array for the addPoint's method
                    var cpu_status = Math.round(dataBody.monit.loadavg[i] * 100) / 100;
                    var arr_time_status = [get_time(), cpu_status];

                    //Executing the addPoint's method
                    if (charts.series[i].name === '1/Mins'){
                        charts.series[i].addPoint(arr_time_status, true, true);

                    } else if (charts.series[i].name === '5/Mins'){
                        charts.series[i].addPoint(arr_time_status, true, true);

                    } else if (charts.series[i].name === '15/Mins'){
                        charts.series[i].addPoint(arr_time_status, true, true);
                    };
                };
            });
        });
    }, 1000 * 10);
});`
```

Comment: What is the value of arr_time_status? Do you have any errors in the console ?

Comment: no errors, the arr_time_status just like this array [Date.UTC(now), 1.23].

Comment: but this funtion is get from json or you use it manually as you placed? Becuase in the JSON you cannot use any function, hope that you aware of that.

Comment: it's not a function , it's a number : like +new Date()

Comment: Ok, so I need a live demo, could you supply it?

Comment: sorry, i just run it on my computer, could you leave your email or other contacts for me ? thank you so much . i am a chinese and you ?  so i got off work , see you tomorrow.

Comment: feel free to contact with us by SO, or support@highcharts.com

Comment: hi, the code has been deployed to online and just for testing,  looking at the http://115.28.240.69 , the login user: hisense     pass: 123.com

Comment: the first chart is work and the second chart got a problem, please check it out